# Warning about Unknown HTTP requests

Tags: spring, server

As soon as I start the spring project server,
so many warning msgs on my console section like these down below

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/phpmyadmin3333/index.php] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/php2MyAdmin/index.php] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/phpNyAdmin/index.php] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/1/index.php] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

I didn't even request all of them(i mean URI) but just keep happening!
I kinda freaked out right now

Comment: Something, somewhere, tries to send request to your server. Remove your network cable and deactivate wifi. If you still receive these requests, it comes from something on your computer and looks like malware. Otherwise, it comes from somewhere else, and a firewall would be welcome.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks man i just downloaded malware zero kit. i was scare to death at the moment.